# 2 different game center apple Ids one village

Tags: clash-of-clans

someone logged into their game center earlier on my phone. Then, they loaded their Clash of Clans village and played it. After they were done, I logged them out of the game center and logged myself back in. Later on I went to play my village and it's stuck on his village. I've logged into multiple different game centers to see if it would load their village or start from townhall 1, but it's always stuck on his village. I want to get my village back. What's going on? Why won't it load another game center progress or even start over then have a pop up asking if you want to load Town hall 8 village?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like supercell has actually stopped everyone from using multiple accounts, I hope they change their minds about this!! It is going to affect lots of people and lots of bases, hope they reverse this.